# What are key things to test in ArcMap 10.1, service pack 1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have been asked to test service pack 1 for ArcMap 10.1 before it is provided to other users at my university. Are there any key things I should do for any SP test, or should I try to look at things that have specifically been addressed in this SP?

My plan was to create a new .mxd file and run a few basic geoprocessing commands. Realistically I'm not going to able to check everything, but are there other key things I should do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest testing those things that most of your users may use.  The service pack [Issues Addressed](http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/ArcGIS101sp1-issues.htm#Server-sp1) page is grouped by application theme (e.g. ArcGIS for Desktop, ArcGIS for Server...etc) to help you test against.

Comment: As artwor21 suggests. Find some users from different areas. Ask for some ideas of normal tasks and processes they perform.  Especially any third party software used.

Comment: This answer and comment have made me think about the type of information I should be collecting from our users. I don't currently have details of specific issues users have had, so my main concern was that installation of the SP might have unintended consequences (is that likely?). I ran through a few basic geoprocessing commands, ran a couple of python scripts using shps and gdbs, and used Spatial Ecology's GME, as these are the sorts of things people seem to do here.

Answer (score 7):

The big new features at 10.1 SP1:

- [64-bit background geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/31/announcing-64-bit-geoprocessing/)
- [Parallel processing factor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000004m000000) environment setting on certain tools
- [`arcpy.da.Walk`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000) function
- Better JSON, WKB and WKT support in arcpy
- Some improvements to the (still) [rather annoying](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/61365-Disabling-the-ArcGIS-Online-Connection-in-10.1) ArcGIS Connection Utility
- [Various improvements for ArcGIS for Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/What_s_new_in_ArcGIS_10_1_SP1_for_Server/01540000060s000000/)

A more easily digestible list is here: [What's new in ArcGIS 10.1 service packs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//016w0000005q000000)

Specifically for geoprocessing: [What's new in geoprocessing in ArcGIS 10.1 service packs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_s_new_in_geoprocessing_in_ArcGIS_10_1_service_packs/016w0000005r000000/)

Answer (score 6):

One major update with ArcGIS 10 SP1 is [64-Bit Background Geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/31/announcing-64-bit-geoprocessing/), available as a separate download [here](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1913).  There are major implications for any organization that process big-data:

> This 64-bit installation (which requires a 64-bit operating system)
>   will replace your current background processing. All scripts, models
>   and tools which execute in the background will use a 64-bit process.
>   Your biggest benefit when using 64-bit Background processing is that
>   using 64-bit applications allow your large processes to take advantage
>   of more memory (if available) than when using a 32-bit application.

I think you will find a lot of interest in this new feature and it would be easy to incorporate this into a presentation.  I've personally had great success using 64-bit background geoprocessing on memory expansive operations such as [Integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000), where 32-bit processing had previously failed.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding 10.1 SP1 bugs, we discovered one that caused us major headaches.  I'm not sure if it affects every installation, but it was a problem on three of our computers.  See a description of problem and cause on the Esri discussion forum, http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/72244-ArcMap-10.1-SP1-crashing-frequently.

In a nutshell:  Having the Georeferencing Toolbar turned on, and rasters loaded in the map document, eventually causes crashing.

sarah

Answer (score 3):

One thing not mentioned already is that if you kept a record of outstanding bugs (and enhancements) that your users have been affected by (or were looking for) in 10.1 (and earlier releases), then that list is what I would recommend testing first.

Answer (score 2):

There is an annoying bug in 10.1 that when you issue the exact same GET request / QueryTask to ArcGIS Server, it fails on alternate requests. Looks like it may be fixed in for SP2. @Derek Swingley who works for Esri pointed this out. NIM086349 
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/72894-Etags-and-Intermittent-QueryTask-Server-Errors

Comment: I think this would be better as a Comment because it is hard to test something fixed in 10.1 SP2 using 10.1 SP1 :-)